# Adb connection Error:EOF (new in android )

Tags: java, android, android-layout

and trying to make a project in which my app will be connected to the database and will fetch the required values as I command it to do.

I just made the designing part and tried to run it and see it.

But its giving an error: Adb connection Error:EOF

please help me to solve it

My Android Console shows:

```
[2014-01-14 12:30:33 - Emulator] error libGL.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[2014-01-14 12:30:33 - Emulator] Failed to load libGL.so
[2014-01-14 12:30:33 - Emulator] error libGL.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: yes, it will helpful if you show console output, what actually happens, either in ddms or android console

Comment: hey I have edited and post what my android console is showing

Comment: @user3192893 Adb connection Error:EOF where is this one ?

Comment: " Adb connection Error:EOF " was showing in my ddms console

Answer (score 8):

Well you could try this out:

1. Open your cmd .Go to Platform-tools/ path
2. Run the cmd like : adb kill-server
3. Then : adb start-server
4. Restart the Eclipse

Also Delete the AVD and Create the New One if  above don't Work

Hope this could help...

Answer (score 1):

ok, i have seen all people answer such question under eclipse, but actually i met it in android studio. Here is my working out step:

1. open android device monitor and watch system output, error like above
2. open the terminal button in android studio where you can find it in left bottom and click the button then find the terminal.
3. `adb kill-server`
4. `adb devices`(here is the success status output)

   - daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
   - daemon started successfully *

**Attention**:if you do such behavior in your mac terminal or windows cmd.it's useless, i have tried that way and restart android studio finally failed.

Answer (score 0):

Please setting up the development mode for your test-device-phone .if it is not work, your could try restart your eclipse

Answer (score 0):

simply go to your cmd terminal and type.

1. adb kill-server
2. adb start-server

and then rebuild your project